# "working" jar archive can be opened through console but not directly with the java.exe

Tags: java

Does anyone know that problem?
I thought you could open executable `.jar` files with the `java.exe`.

When I run the `.jar` file from the cmd console with `java -jar filename.jar` it works completely fine and runs as intended.
But when I tell it to open with the same `java.exe` that begins to run when I use the console command it gives:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FilePath/filename.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FilePath/filename.jar
```

I first tried it with the `java.exe` in `/bin/` from the built-in JRE from the JDK.

Then I downloaded the JRE from Oracle's website and used the `java.exe` in the `/bin/` folder there.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: FilePath/filename.jar` thats the actuall message?

Comment: **Wow** I am _impressed_ how much you can highlight for increased **readability**.

Comment: @Antoniossss No, it isn't. It uses the file path on to that file and the name of the jar. `C:\Users\TehHackerlord1337\Desktop\Cheese_jar\Cheese.jar` substitutes `FilePath/filename.jar` while TehHackerlord1337 is my username and Cheese.jar is the name of the jar-file.

Comment: I did delete the registry key entry for the default app to open .jar files according to: https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7
because it was suggesting to open the .jar file with a JRE version that I had already uninstalled.

Comment: I wonder why it is looking for class `*.jar` so I asked is that the real message as it supposed to be eg `some.package.ClassName`

Comment: This is my manifest:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.cheese.JChess`





is something wrong with it?
It was automatically generated by IntelliJ Ideas Artifact Building feature.

Comment: There are new lines between them and also after the `Main-Class` row. Since from my testing around because of this problem I noticed that if you don't have a new line after the `Main-Class` row the **manifest** is recognized as corrupt. So it's not that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a file `C:\MyProject\app.jar`.

When you run the following on the command line:

```
java -jar C:\MyProject\app.jar  # This works.
```

it works fine. The error you are seeing is the error you would get if you execute the following:

```
java C:\MyProject\app.jar       # This won't.
```

Note the missing `-jar` option. The solution is to write it like the first snippet: that `-jar` option is required. If this is happening when you doubleclick on it, your OS settings are messed up. If this is happening in a script, fix the script. If this is happening on the command line, write it with the `-jar` bit.

Comment: So do you know how to amend those messed up OS settings?

Comment: rzwitserloot
I did delete the registry key entry for the default app to open .jar files according to: superuser.com/questions/49615/… because it was suggesting to open the .jar file with a JRE version that I had already uninstalled.